# sqli multi-query combine two queries on a single one

Tags: sql, subquery, multi-query

I have a situation where I have a large table and Im making two queries and
I want to combine them into a single one. Say I have a table like this:

```
Name |LastName|Address|State
---------------------------
John |Carter  |23 Blv | CA
Bill |Carter  |23 Blv | CA
Joe  |Carter  |23 Blv | CA
Steve|Carter  |23 Blv | CA
```

the first query is

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name LIKE '%query%' OR  LastName LIKE '%query%'
```

the second is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Address LIKE '%query%' OR  State LIKE '%query%'
```

The reason why Im doing this is because I want results to be ordered based
on Name|Surname first and then append more results based on Address|State.

Cany anybody help to make it a single query? **I am using **SQLite*** by the way.*

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name LIKE '%query%' OR  LastName LIKE '%query%'
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Address LIKE '%query%' OR  State LIKE '%query%'
ORDER BY Name, Surname, State
```